# modify mod_mainmenu to get hover text on menu items

Tags: php, css, joomla

I have used mod_mainmenu for my menu bar. Now i want to have a text when i hover my mouse over the menu item. can any body help me out.

Please also tell the file and where  i have to do the modifications.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: What is your joomla version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mod_mainmenu go to the place where the menu is created. Added a `title` attribute to the `anchor<a>`.

EG:

```
<a href="/index.php?title=Talk:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/" title="Discussion about the content page">Discussion</a>
```

Comment: heyy Dasun thanks a ton man.. you are a life saver.. Just used the title trick and some conditional statements and get the way i always wanted.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add title attribute in a tag to show it in mousehover. In order to add title in a tag you'll have to modify helper.php of mod_mainmenu.
Here is the path - `modules/mod_mainmenu/helper.php`

In the above file search for this code-

```
switch ($tmp->browserNav)
{
    default:
    case 0:
        // _top
        $data = '<a title="'.$tmp->name.'" href="'.$tmp->url.'">'.$image.$tmp->name.'</a>';
        break;
    case 1:
        // _blank
        $data = '<a title="'.$tmp->name.'" href="'.$tmp->url.'" target="_blank">'.$image.$tmp->name.'</a>';
        break;
    case 2:
        // window.open
        $attribs = 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,'.$this->_params->get('window_open');

        // hrm...this is a bit dickey
        $link = str_replace('index.php', 'index2.php', $tmp->url);
        $data = '<a title="'.$tmp->name.'" href="'.$link.'" onclick="window.open(this.href,\'targetWindow\',\''.$attribs.'\');return false;">'.$image.$tmp->name.'</a>';
        break;
}
```

And add title attribute and it's value there.

You can also try [template overriding](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Irfan but Where to add title tag?? in all the three cases??
can you please write some code for this also

Comment: @user1903194:title should be in a tag.I have update the answer.let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Thanks Irfan. but when i used this code all my menu item got vanished.. :(. I am using the exact code.

Comment: Thanks Irfan for giving your attention for my question. my query is solved. used the title trick and conditional statements and it worked..
thanks a ton man.. :)